# Custom validation attribute's set error message not showing as predicted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom validation attribute:

```
public class RequireIfPropertyIsFalseAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private string basisProperty { get; set; }
        public RequireIfPropertyIsFalseAttribute(string basisProperty)
        {
            this.basisProperty = basisProperty;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var basisProp = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(basisProperty);
            var isFalse = !(bool)basisProp.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (isFalse)
            {
                if (value == null || (value.GetType() == typeof(string) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(((string)value).Trim())))
                        return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

I use it for both Model properties:

```
public bool NoAgeProvided { get; set; }
[RequireIfPropertyIsFalse(nameof(NoAgeProvided), ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
[Display(Name = "Age")]
public int Age { get; set; }

public bool NoNameProvided { get; set; }
[RequireIfPropertyIsFalse(nameof(NoNameProvided), ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Upon validation, the Name validation message shows "This is required". However, for the Age property, "The Age field is required" is displaying on the validation message. What am I doing wrong?
How can I display the set ErrorMessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because property `Age` is typeof `int`, it is always required (an `int` cannot be `null`) and if you leave the textbox empty, a `null` value is submitted and the Required validation is executed first and that error message is displayed.

Change you property to be nullable

```
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

Note that it works for your `Name` property because its `string` which is nullable by default.

As a side note, you should consider implementing `IClientValidatable` so that you can get client side validation as well. Refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2).

Comment: I suspected that that is the case. However, making the field nullable would also mean I have to change the associated database table column's is null attribute. I'll read the link that you provided. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your editing data so you ALWAYS use a view model, not data models in a view.

Comment: In any case, what would you expect to store in that db column if its not provided (a value of `0` would not make sense)

Comment: Tbh the client's requirements are murky right now, I have a non nullable table column and a nullable model property. I was hoping I could find a way to make the validation for the contrasting nature of the two fields. The requirements may change in the future, but for now I am working for a solution. I am still reading the link that you provided, thanks!